# C++ - invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I am trying to use [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) to sort a list of structs. But I am getting the error:

`invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::__list_iterator<process, void *>' and 'int') __sort3<_Compare>(__first, __first+1, __j, __comp);`

**Struct:**

```
struct process {
   int process_id;
   int cpu_cycles;
   int mem_footprint;
};
```

**Main function:**

```
int main() {

    list<process> process_list;

    init_process_list(process_list);
    sort(process_list.begin(), process_list.end(), compare_pid);

}
```

**init_process_list:**

```
void init_process_list(list<process> &p_list) {

    cout << "\n>> Generating process list...";

    generator generate; // Random number generator class
    process p;

    for(int i = 0; i < process_count; i++) {
        p.process_id = i;
        p.cpu_cycles = generate.rand_num_between(cycle_lbound, cycle_ubound);
        p.mem_footprint = generate.rand_num_between(mem_lbound, mem_ubound);
        p_list.push_back(p);
    }

    cout << "Done" << endl;

}
```

**compare_pid:**

```
bool compare_pid(process &lhs, process &rhs) { 
    return lhs.cpu_cycles < rhs.cpu_cycles;  
}
```

I want to sort all the process items in the list by their cpu_cylcles value in the ascending order. I also made the compare_pid function which takes in two process and returns a boolean. I can't figure out what the error is. Can someone please help?

Comment: First guess: lack of `const` in the predicate

Comment: @MooingDuck Tried adding const and no luck. Still the same error

Comment: `std::sort` requires RandomAccessIterators, `std::list`'s are BiDirectional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> invalid operands to binary expression
>   ('std::__1::__list_iterator' and 'int')
>   __sort3<_Compare>(__first, __first+1, __j, __comp);

Alright, that third line of code is somwhere in `std::sort`.  The only operator there is `+`.  So the expression with the error is `__first+1` where `__first` is a `list<process>::iterator`.  List iterators do not have a `iterator+int` overload, because they are bidirectional iterators, but NOT random access.

You cannot call `std::sort` on a `std::list`.  Use a `std::vector` instead, or another container with random access iterators.

Comment: That worked. Will accept the answer when the time limit is passed. Thanks